# Adding a link to dhtmlxGrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dhtmlx

I'm using dhtmlxGrid and I have a number of records that I'm returning from a query in ColdFusion. I'm then looping over that record set and creating JSON and having the grid parse that.

What I'm interested in is adding a HTML link to one column so that use that link to go to a different page for that specific record.

There is an example of this here: http://www.dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxGrid/samples/01_cell_types/04_link_grid.html

The question I have is that I'm using.

```
mygrid.parse(data, "json");
```

to load the data into the grid and according to the docs link are created by passing an XML file to the grid like this:

```
mygrid.loadXML("../common/grid_links.xml");
```

It seems that if I loaded this XML it would screw up my grid that has been created with JSON.

I'm curious if anyone has had the same situation or could I possible use the

```
mygrid.parse(somenewdata, "json");
```

to load in the HTML information?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

Is your XML have and header

```
<?php  
header ("Content-Type:text/xml");  
echo '....your xml data.....';
exit();
?>
```

It's screwed up your DHTMLX Grid data because your XML data is not properly as example shown on DHTMLX. Set to properly data in XML as examples: http://www.dhtmlx.com/docs/products/docsExplorer/doc/dhtmlxxml/index.html

So make sure that your XML file are exactly and properly as simple above. Be carefully when you use ISO data under XML tag: `<![CDATA[` and closed `]]>` tag inside `<cell>` tag. If isn't readable and not giving properly results it will thrown up with errors.

Point to this documentation maybe it's helpful for you: http://docs.dhtmlx.com/doku.php?id=dhtmlxgrid:configuration_from_xml

Hope this helps.

---

For JSON look at best describes as examples:
 JSON PHP file: http://www.dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxGrid/samples/12_initialization_loading/09_init_grid_json.html

and Grid rendered layout: http://www.dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxGrid/samples/12_initialization_loading/09_init_grid_json.html

If you want that JSON file calling from URI started with "http://..." just make sure that loaded as PHP file and inside PHP file render with `json_encode()` data or call it manually to another source within PHP. So your files need only to render example:

---

`JSON PHP FILE   myjson.php?callsome=1`

```
<?php 

if ($_GET["callsome"] == "1")
{
    header('Content-type: application/json');

    echo file_get_contents('http://www.somewhere.com/some.json');

    exit();
}
```

And call to parse:

```
 mygrid.parse("/myjson.php?callsome=1", "json");
```

Or if you need directly assign as example for including data:

```
 <?php

 $var = file_get_contents('some_json_data.php');

 echo $var; // your returned JSON data from included
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I was just looking around the docs and I'm loading the grid with JSON data. Will this only work in XML or can I pass the link info to my JSON using something like:  Column Data^http://www.somewhere.com?

Comment: I've edited an answer. Look at JSON example how would be. Compare that data for your usage and that's it.

Comment: Thanks I'll take a look when I get back in the office. I'll also try to translate the php to what the ColdFusion equilvent is. Thanks